# How to catch exception in property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have properties defined in a class i want to capture the exception but not sure how to do .

Below is the code that i use:

```
 public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ABC> CachedADetails { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<int, ABC> TableById { get; set; }
```

I tried adding catch and try block above this but it didn't help me

So how do i capture exception from the above code?

Like i have a cache service and the accessor prop could be null so if it is null then i want to capture the exception and throw it.

Comment: I'm not sure I am following your question. Can you show us 1) the entire class, and 2) the code where you are using the class?

Comment: Those are auto-implemented properties which _cannot_ throw exceptions.